# yii2 get label of optgroup when submit

Tags: yii2

I have a select box:

```
<select id="issue-users_id" class="form-control" name="Issue[users_id]">
  <optgroup label="user">
    <option value="16">user</option>
    <option value="24">robo</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="group">
   <option value="15">123123</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

when submit form I want to have array like this:

```
Issue[users_id][user] = value (16, 24)
or Issue[users_id][group] = value (15)
```

it means I want to get value of optgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is possible is manualy prepare data and send it to server. On submit get form data and replace `Issue.user_id` param:

```
var selected = $('#issue-users_id').find(":selected"),
    optgroup = selected.closest('optgroup');

if ( optgroup.attr('label') == 'group' ) {
   form_data.Issue.users_id = {
     group: selected.val()
   }
} else {
   form_data.Issue.users_id = {
     user: selected.val()
   }
}

$.ajax(/* send form */);
```

Comment: yes. I have to use jquery but it's a little different your way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve group through user id. User id is unique and can belong to one or more groups, so you can create method for this in according model, for example:

```
public function getGroup()
{
    // return group name string here based on $this->id
}
```

Getting the value of optgroup from `$_POST` array is illogical.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but in my case, id of user and id of group maybe the same :) so I need to get label of optgroup to distinguish

Comment: Yes, but how it relates to this? User id should be enough for getting groups he belongs to via database relations. Retrieving it from `$_POST` is wrong.